# Как превратить нарисованную от руки линию в красивый график?

Tags: графика, математика

Для своего диплома я хочу сделать компонент (если не получится, то фиг с ним:), который при рисовании линии (я использую WPF InkCanvas) превращал бы эту линую в график. Ну то есть выпрямлял посильнее. Не силен в математике, поэтому не знаю, что мне нужно использовать для этого. В качестве входных данных имеется набор точек. Что можно применить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей уже есть готовый [алгоритм Рамера-Дугласа-Пекера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) Он вроде применяется в векторных графических редакторах и картографии.

И еще список алгоритмов делающих тоже самое:

- [Visvalingam–Whyatt algorithm](http://archive.today/Tzq2)
- [Reumann–Witkam algorithm](http://web.cs.sunyit.edu/~poissad/projects/Curve/about_algorithms/reumann.php)
- [Opheim simplification algorithm](http://psimpl.sourceforge.net/opheim.html)
- [Lang simplification algorithm](http://web.cs.sunyit.edu/~poissad/projects/Curve/about_algorithms/lang.php)

Затем полученную ломанную можно превратить в красивую кривую каким-нибудь алгоритмом интерполяции или использовать точки как опорные для построения кривых Безье.

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб: взять крайние точки исходной линии, найти равно распределенные точки "изломов". Получаем промежутки-условия. Потом для каждого такого промежутка ищем точки, которые в него попадают и находим простейшее среднеарифметическое значение для X и для Y. Получим усредненные значения на участках, соединим их точками - тот же график, но менее детализированный. Больше точек - больше изломов - картинка ближе к графику.

Comment: Я не совсем понял про равно распределенные точки изломов. И можно ли просто брать все точки через шаг по х, например?

Comment: Допустим, крайние точки линии у тебя (1,4) и (12, 24). Ты хочешь сделать график из 2 отрезков (т.е. усреднить до 3 точек). По X ограничения 1-4, 4-8, 8-12, по Y: 4-10, 10-16, 16-24, т.е. первый отрезок заменим на точку, попадающую в: {1<x<=4; 4<y<=10}, второй - {4<x<=8; 10<y<=16}, третий - {8<x<=12; 16<y<=24}. Усредняя значения точек, попающих в эти промежутки, получаются 3 точки, которые можно соединять линией графика.

Comment: Через шаг - та же ерунда, только нужно либо искать кратный шаг, либо вводить какие-то коэффициенты на крайнем промежутке... Короче, не научно это)

Comment: По сути, ты просто делишь график на равные промежутки (по каждой оси) и ищешь на каждом промежутке среднюю точку. И вся любовь.

Comment: ну в общем спасибо, я еще переосмыслю